# Laravel hasOne relation with where clause

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model called `RealEstate`, this model has a relation with another model called `TokenPrice`, I needed to access the oldest records of `token_prices` table using by a simple `hasOne` relation, So I did it and now my relation method is like following:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class RealEstate extends Model
{
    public function firstTokenPrice(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(TokenPrice::class)->oldestOfMany();
    }
}
```

By far it's fine and no complexity. But now, I need to involve another relation into `firstTokenPrice`.

Let me explain a bit more:

As my project grown, the more complexity was added it, like changing `firstTokenPrice` using by a third table called `opening_prices`, so I added a new relation to `RealEstate` called `lastOpeningPrice`:

```php
public function lastOpeningPrice(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(OpeningPrice::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

So the deal with simplicity of `firstTokenPrice` relation is now off the table, I want to do something like following every time a `RealEstate` object calls for its `firstTokenPrice`:

> Check for `lastOpeningPrice`, if it was exists, then `firstTokenPrice` must returns a different record of `token_price` table, otherwise the `firstTokenPrice` must returns `oldestOfMany` of `TokenPrice` model.

I did something like following but it's not working:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class RealEstate extends Model
{
    public function lastOpeningPrice(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(OpeningPrice::class)->latestOfMany();
    }

    public function firstTokenPrice(): HasOne
    {
        $lop = $this->lastOpeningPrice;
        if ($lop) {
            TokenPriceHelper::getOrCreateFirstToken($this, $lop->amount); // this is just a helper function that inserts a new token price into `token_prices` table, if there was none exists already with selected amount
            return $this->hasOne(TokenPrice::class)->where('amount', $lop->amount)->oldestOfMany();
        }
        return $this->hasOne(TokenPrice::class)->oldestOfMany();
    }
}
```

I have checked the `$this->hasOne(TokenPrice::class)->where('amount', $lop->amount)->oldestOfMany()` using by `->toSql()` method and it returns something unusual.

**I need to return a `HasOne` object inside of `firstTokenPrice` method.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ofMany builder for that purpose:

```
    public function firstTokenPrice(): HasOne
    {
        $lop = $this->lastOpeningPrice;
        if ($lop) {
            TokenPriceHelper::getOrCreateFirstToken($this, $lop->amount); // this is just a helper function that inserts a new token price into `token_prices` table, if there was none exists already with selected amount
            return $this->hasOne(TokenPrice::class)->ofMany([
                'id' => 'min',
            ], function ($query) use ($lop) {
                $query->where('amount', $lop->amount);
            });
        }
        return $this->hasOne(TokenPrice::class)->oldestOfMany();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's working as my own. I'll post it as an answer. please check it out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I used `->oldest()` with a custom scope called `amounted` in `TokenPrice` model:

```php
class TokenPrice extends Model
{
    public function scopeAmounted(Builder $query, OpeningPrice $openingPrice): Builder
    {
        return $query->where('amount', $openingPrice->amount);
    }

    /....
}
```

And then changed my `firstTokenPrice`

```php
public function firstTokenPrice(): HasOne
{
    $lop = $this->lastOpeningPrice;
    if ($lop) {
        TokenPriceHelper::getOrCreateFirstToken($this, $lop->amount);
        return $this->hasOne(TokenPrice::class)->amounted($lop)->oldest();
    }
    return $this->hasOne(TokenPrice::class)->oldestOfMany();
}
```

**It's working, but I don't know if it's the best answer or not**

Comment: @alternativeminded Please check this out :-)